# First @media query CSS not working

Tags: css, wordpress, responsive-design, media-queries

i'm currently working to develop a WordPress theme, but when i put the first @media query in the style.css file, just the first one there is not working. All others @media from the second is work fine! the problem is with first one only.

Here i put my current work, there is a problem with coding web standards or something like that on my following code?

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
    #content .content-area {
        border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
        width: 50%;
    }

}

@media screen and (max-width: 991px) {
    .hfeed{}

    #content {
        width: 100%;
        overflow: auto;
    }

    .content-area {
        padding: 8% 3%;
        width: 63%
    }

    #header-sidebar p.site-description {
        font-size: 120%;
    }
}
```

this is just a little part of my work.

When i make a copy of it, it works perfectly, though is the same @media content:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
    #content .content-area {
        border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
        width: 50%;
    }

}

@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
    #content .content-area {
        border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
        width: 50%;
    }

}
```

Why?!

Comment: Can you post a fiddle? http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Most likely a syntax error before the code you posted.

Comment: You are right @AdamBuchananSmith . now its work perfectly!
the error was the following comment:
// Responsive Theme 
but it is an absurd think, who can a simple comment affects  that? i want just understand :)

Thank you!

Comment: OK great! simple fixes are always best

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone seeing this question, it has been answer in the comments:

"Most likely a syntax error before the code you posted."